# How to get active rent's details for given month

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

I want to get active rent's for given month. I have a table where i have rent details. In that table i have start date, end date and how many months. So when i select a month i want to know what are the rents currently active using mysql

Example

```
House A 1.1.2019  31.12.2019  12
House B 1.2.2019  31.05.2019  03
House C 1.4.2019  31.12.2019  08
```

If i select month June result should be House A and House C, and if i select march result should be All three (A, B, C)

Can someone help me with mysql query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the overlapping range problem, where the first range is the range of rents dates, and the second range is the span of a certain month.  For June, 2019, we can try:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE rent_end >= '2019-06-01' AND rent_start <= '2019-06-30';
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: I only get records that match start and end date only

Comment: I don't understand your comment, and my query seems to be working with all your sample data.

Comment: plz check below images